# Automatically running macro when CommentThreaded is modified?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column whose cells have comments via [CommentsThreaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentsthreaded) and [CommentThreaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded) objects. In another column, I successfully copy the contents of these threads using the function `=GetComments(A1)`, as shown below:

```
' Returns the concatenated string of parent and child comments for the specified input cell.
Function GetComments(SelectedCell As Range) As String
    Set CellComment = SelectedCell.CommentThreaded
    Dim Result As String
    If Not CellComment Is Nothing Then
        Result = CellComment.Author.Name & ": """ & CellComment.Text & """ " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Dim ChildCount As Integer
        ChildCount = 1
        For Each ChildComment In CellComment.Replies
            Result = Result & "[Reply #" & ChildCount & "] " & ChildComment.Author.Name & ": """ & ChildComment.Text & """ " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            ChildCount = ChildCount + 1
        Next
    Else
        Result = "No Comments"
    End If
    GetComments = Result
End Function
```

Example output would be: `John Doe: "My comment"`

However, I've noticed that when a comment is added/edited/deleted, the output cell that uses the `GetComments` function is not updated. I have to manually re-run the function in the output cell to get its contents to update by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I've tried using all of the typical event handlers, such as `Worksheet.Change`, `SelectionChange`, etc. None of the events fire when a comment is modified. Neither does manually forcing `Volatile` or `Calculate`. It's almost like the Add/Delete/Edit methods of `CommentsThreaded` are not included in workbook events at all.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe one of this solution help you? (They are not ideal:/ ) https://superuser.com/questions/1261444/custom-formula-not-updating

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that question, but doing `Now()` works as a hacky solution. I just tested it. If you'd like to post this comment as a solution, I'll happily give you the credit.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much. It is so nice:) (I needed it today:) ) I happy I could helped you:)

Comment: Maybe one of this solution help you? (They are not ideal:/ ) superuser.com/questions/1261444/custom-formula-not-updating